# How to avoid 'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"session not created"}} in selenium webdriver quit() method?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am running very complex selenium tests on non-public webpages. In most cases these tests run fine, but sometimes they fail in the `webdriver.quit()` method!

Here is an example of the error:

```
bsp_usecase_tests/tools/selNG.py:299: in quit
    self.webdriver.quit()
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py:187: in quit
    RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:606: in quit
    self.execute(Command.QUIT)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:311: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)[0m
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f091b065550>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"Tried to run command without establishing...s::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start\n                        at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84"}}'}
```

Used packages:

- selenium 3.8.0
- pytest 3.4.0
- geckodriver 0.19.1

Top level workflow

```
mydriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, log_path=logfile)
...
do a single test here. Navigate to URL, login, click etc.
...
mydriver.stop_client()
mydriver.quit()
```

The error roughly appears in about 1-2% of all cases...

What is the right action to do here?

- Catch the error and just ignore it? I mean, the tests have run already...
- A loop trying to quit again?
- Anything else?

Comment: Are you running them parallel? Could you please share the example workflow?

Comment: No parallel tests. For a single test I create a webdriver, then shut it down. I will expand the description a bit...

Comment: Try to add a pause before `mydriver.stop_client()` like `time.sleep(5)`

Comment: put the code  under try and except blocks. Sometimes there is lack of response from your target DB and the javascript that is run by selenium. That is normal thing. Back in the days i would put some 2 second waits just to be sure that the page is loaded etc. If the target is e.g in USA and you are in EU, then sometimes there is normal delay like 1 or 2 seconds and therefore these types of errors appear. Now without seeing your live code, these are the topics i have in my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try them out...

Comment: What can be `stop_client()` all about?

Comment: No idea what `stop_client` means.

Comment: Why are using `stop_client` then )))?

Answer (score 0):

### stop_client()

As per the *Selenium-Python API Documentation* [**`stop_client()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.stop_client) is called after executing the `quit()` command. This method may be overridden to define custom shutdown behavior.

- Source Code:

  ```
  def stop_client(self):
  """
  Called after executing a quit command. This method may be overridden to define custom shutdown behavior.
  """
  pass
  ```

---

This error message...

```
bsp_usecase_tests/tools/selNG.py:299: in quit
    self.webdriver.quit()
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f091b065550>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"Tried to run command without establishing...s::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start\n
```

...implies that when `quit()` method was invoked `'status': 500` was returned as there was no active session.

In your code block:

- First `stop_client()` was invoked which is overridden within your project code to define the custom shutdown behavior.
- Next `quit()` is invoked.
- This sequence is just the opposite of the intended sequence.

### Solution

Reversing the code lines as follows will solve your issue:

```
mydriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, log_path=logfile)
...
do a single test here. Navigate to URL, login, click etc.
...
mydriver.quit()
mydriver.stop_client()
```